# Laravel Custom Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]

Very silly situation, The point is I can not change the database architecture because its a running e-commerce business having more then 1m active users.

Here is my situation.

Table User:
Table Store:

Both have same primary key, mean we can call the one to one relation.
But now I have to create belongs to many relation form Store to User.

store table have two columns

1. slug
2. parentId

Now I need to get all users having slug of store

So my query is

```
select * from users where id IN (select id from store where slug = ?);
```

How can I create a relation in this situation.

Comment: wait, the id of the user and the store is the same..? what about using `HasOne` relationship while overriding the keys? like `$userModel->HasOne('store', 'id', 'id')`. however, the `where slug = ?` is a bit difficult on the relation definition, you can bet on `User::with('store', function($q){ $q->whereNotNull('slug') })->get()`. i can think of that way, but i havent fiddling laravel for years now >.< cmiiw

Comment: nops the situation is a user will have on store and store can have many users but identification key is store slug not the id now.

If I will perform one to one relation on user > store then I need to check parentId of store, if store's has a parent Id then the target store will be having slug same as store but null parent id.

Comment: does this make sense ?

Comment: Hi @MoeenBasra, I think the problem is not completly clear to understand. I have the same question about the ID of users and store, and I could not get it any clearer with your answer. Maybe you could add your DB diagram and state both: (1) what is the CURRENT behavior and (2) what is the DESIRED behavior. I either see what would be the problem on updating the db schema even if its a 1m users prd app. Not trivial, but not either impossible if you come to an actual need on this.

Comment: I'm adding a small schema snippet please have a look again

Answer (score 0):

Hey there i would try to answer in detail as much as possible.

**Create the following relationships:**

For store:

```
public function users(){
   return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id' ,'slug');
}
```

For user:

```
public function store(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
}
```

**Create a new controller and write a new function as below:**

```
public function getStoreUsers(){
  $users = Store::where('slug','yourvalue')->firstOrFail()->users;
  return response()->json($users);
}
```

The function above will return a collection of users which have theirs 'id' equals to store 'slug'

**In case if you have many stores you can do the follwing:**

```
public function getStoreUsers(){
 $stores = Store::all();
 $storeUsers;

 foreach($stores as $store){
   $users = $store->users;
   $storeUsers[$store['id']] = array($users);
   return response()->json($storeUsers);
 }
}
```

This function will return an array of users of each store.

I have answered according to my understanding of your question if any erros occur please reply below so i can fix if possible. I Hope this is what you wanted if not let me know.

**UPDATE:**

This is what i could understand from your request.

Store a , store b , store c has slug = xyz.
you have 50,000 users. 10,000 of them has slug xyz. and you need the information of those 10,000 users. if thats the case then the code below will help you out.

```
public function getStoreUsers(){
   $slugtomatch = 'xyz';
   $result;
   $stores = Store::where('slug',$slugtomatch)->get();

foreach($stores as $store){
   $users = $store->users;
   $result = array($users);
  }

return response()->json($result);

}
```

This will return an array of users those have the $slugtomatch value in their slug fields.

Comment: I appreciate you contribution but I guess you did not properly understood my problem I just updated the question and also add a small schema example.

Comment: so you need users of stores those are actual (parent id not null)?

Comment: I need all users having same slug.

e.g main store have a slug 'abc'  then I need to get Id of all users having slug "abc" now I have user ids now I need to get users.
this is one solution in my mind but may be you can provide me some good example.

Comment: I Have updated my answer , take a look and let me know if thats what you want.

Comment: This approach is manual which I'm already using. I need a dynamic relation from store to users using same approach.

Comment: can you explain dynamic , i do not know why i am having a feeling that i know the solution but i do not know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182187/discussion-between-moeen-basra-and-amir-qureshi).